# Close first dropdown if open the second one

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have multiple dropdowns. Now when i open one dropdown. and then open the second one. Both are open and the content is the same. I want, if the user want to open a second one the first one will close.

```
{this.state.MainChannels.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <Category key={item.name} >

                            <CategoryContainer >
                                <CheckboxLabel>

                                    <CheckboxInput type="checkbox" checked={item.followed} onChange={() => this.handleCheckAllSubCategories(item)} >

                                    </CheckboxInput>

                                    <CheckboxButton className="fa fa-check"  >


                                    </CheckboxButton>

                                </CheckboxLabel>
                                <CategoryTitle>
                                    {item.name}
                                </CategoryTitle>
                                <ChannelImage style={{ backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(27,31,31,1) ,  rgba(255,255,255,0)),  url(${item.image})` }}>

                                </ChannelImage>

                            </CategoryContainer>

                            <OpenInput type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.handleChannel(item.name)}>

                            </OpenInput>

                            <OpenButton className="fa fa-chevron-down" >

                            </OpenButton>
                            {subChannels.map((item2, i): any => {

                                return (
                                    <Subcategories key={i} >


                                        <SubCheckboxLabel>
                                            <SubCheckboxInput id={item2.name} type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.handleCheckbox(item2.name)} checked={item2.followed}>

                                            </SubCheckboxInput>
                                            <SubCheckboxButton className="fa fa-check" >

                                            </SubCheckboxButton>
                                            <SubCategoryTitle>
                                                {item2.name}
                                            </SubCategoryTitle>
                                            <div>

                                            </div>
                                        </SubCheckboxLabel>
                                    </Subcategories>)
                            })}

                        </Category>



                    );
                }


const OpenInput = styled.input`
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 50px;
width: 40px;
z-index: 1000;
opacity: 0;
cursor:pointer;
&:checked ~ p {
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

&:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
}
const OpenInput = styled.input`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    &:checked ~ p {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

&:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
}
```

`

My Problem is this last block. if the user clicks on Open input. The "ul" parts will be displayed. How can i replace this with some JS?

Here a picture what the problem is:

[image]

We see there is the same content. That should not be it should close one dropdown

Comment: Please provide a minimal repro of you problem and/or more code. I usually handle it by adding a class to each item and onclick, the method will close them all and open `event.target`.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from this code how you're deciding what is open or closed as we can't see what your handlers are doing, but I'd suggest using state to keep track of which item is open based on the item name (assuming it is unique).

Then it would be as simple as passing a boolean to your dropdown, 'isOpen' for example, based on the current item in the state, which would be updated by the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the example with accordions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s6l9nn?file=index.js) that i was talking about in the comment section. You can use the same principle to open/close your dropdown :

.ts :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const toggleAccordion = e => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('accordion')).forEach(el => el.classList.add('hidden'));
    e.target.classList.remove("hidden");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="accordion hidden" onClick={toggleAccordion}>
        accordion header
        <div className="accordion-content-wrapper">
            <div>Content</div>
            <div>Content</div>
            <div>Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="accordion hidden" onClick={toggleAccordion}>
        accordion header 2
        <div className="accordion-content-wrapper">
            <div>Content</div>
            <div>Content</div>
            <div>Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

.css (not needed with your dropdown i think):

```
.accordion.hidden {
  height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion-content-wrapper{
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now, as i said it may not fit your needs since we don't have enough code to help you. As Rayan Wolton said, th way you handle the open/close aciton on your dropdown is important.